# Webpack compile Marionette source with errors

Tags: javascript, marionette, webpack

Webpack in compile (Marionette v.2.4.3) [/lib/core/backbone.marionette.js:26](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/lib/core/backbone.marionette.js#L26) instead `this` argument set `undefined`. But this argument take `root` variable ([line 10](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/lib/core/backbone.marionette.js#L10)) and he see, what argument is `undefined` (not `this`) and output error.

Pastebin after/compiled code: http://pastebin.com/YKFTLTsV